# Conan WSL install: option 'pybind' doesn't exist

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, pybind11, conan

Update:
I decided to build the makefiles to build the libraries by hand.  That worked. I am leaving this up in case someone has a suggestion as to how to get conan to work.

I am trying to install some libraries in WSL Linux using conan.

One of the libraries is here: https://github.com/Aquaveo/xmscore

I have installed conan, cmake, and xmsconan (see Building-Libraries below).

I am installing xmscore using these instructions:
https://github.com/Aquaveo/xmscore/wiki/Building-Libraries

When I run the command:

```
conan install -pr ../dev/xmsprofile_debug ..
```

I get the following error message:

```
Configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9.4
cppstd=17
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
[options]
xmscore:pybind=False
xmscore:xms=True
[build_requires]
*: pybind11/2.10.0
[env]

ERROR: /home/stboerne/Programming/ThirdParty/xmscore/conanfile.py: Error while initializing options. option 'pybind' doesn't exist
Possible options are []
```

I tried some of the options from here ([Cmake: using conan pybind11 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69781924/cmake-using-conan-pybind11-package)), but nothing here seems to work, and I am too much of a novice to conan.

The command:

```
conan search pybind11 -r=all
```

produces the following output:

```
Existing package recipes:

Remote 'conancenter':
pybind11/2.4.3
pybind11/2.5.0
pybind11/2.6.0
pybind11/2.6.1
pybind11/2.6.2
pybind11/2.7.0
pybind11/2.7.1
pybind11/2.8.1
pybind11/2.9.1
pybind11/2.9.2
pybind11/2.10.0
```

Any suggestions?

TIA